# Getting Cursor Out of a Table

Tags: cursor

I have LibreOffice 7.3.  I have space under a table on a page in which I want to type content.  However, my cursor is stuck in the table.  How can I get it out of the table? Alt+Enter only takes me to the top of the next page.  It does not let me type text in the space under the table.

Comment: Without seeing the document it is difficult to guess what might be the problem. This question seems to be about LibreOffice and is not specifically related to Ubuntu. (Or did you check that the problem does not occur on other OS?)

Comment: Have you tried double-clicking in that area with the mouse?

Comment: @Bodo general software questions where the OS the software is running on is Ubuntu are on-topic here.